# Enable current date in jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I need to enable the 45 days from the cuurent date in my date picker.

Code:

```
   function disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends(date) {
      var m = date.getMonth();
      var d = date.getDate();
      var y = date.getFullYear();

      for (var i = 0; i < disabledSpecificDays.length; i++) {
      if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, disabledSpecificDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
        return [false];
        }
    }

      var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

      return noWeekend[0] ? [true] : [true];
  }
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var fullDate = new Date();
    var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().toString().length) == 1)? '0'+(fullDate.getMonth()+1) : (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
    var twoDigitDate = ((fullDate.getDate().toString().length) == 1)? '0'+(fullDate.getDate()) : (fullDate.getDate());
    var currentDate = twoDigitDate + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + fullDate.getFullYear();
    var values = currentDate.split("-");
    var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1]-1, values[0]);

    var maxdate = new Date(parsed_date);

    maxdate.setDate(parsed_date.getDate() + 45);

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     showButtonPanel: true,

     minDate: fullDate,
     maxDate: maxdate,//new Date(2015, 04,2),
    beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends

});
```

});

When I tried the above code am able to enable 45 days, but the problem is todays date is in disable mode.

Can I know how to enable the current date in date picker with 45 days enabled.

Added the output screen shot
[image]

here if you check today's date 26th is in disabled mode.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or some working code?

Comment: So you want start date should from tomorrow always, is it?

Comment: @MokshShah: I want it from today's date

Comment: Then what your issue? your code seems to be working fine.

Comment: tip parsed_date = new Date(values[2]-1, values[1]-1, values[0]); you have tried?

Comment: As its a current date, it's focused by default, but its not `disabled` its actually `enabled and selectable`

Comment: I have added the output screenshot. Please check it.

Comment: Works for me too. What does the function ´disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends()´ do? Maybe there is the issue. Have you tried it without the ´beforeShowDay´ callback?

Comment: @ElDevoper   Added the disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends() method as well

Comment: Added the disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends() method as well

Answer (score 0):

try this code this,

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
     enddate:"+45d"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `|| new Date() > date` in your `disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends` function. Since you already set the minDate for the Timepicker you won't need it.

Explanation: `New Date()` is NOW (todays date with the actual time). And `date` is the given date at 0:00h. So it will always be bigger for today's date, except at 0:00h.

Oh and `return noWeekend[0] ? [true] : [true];` doesn't make sense. Should be `return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];` I guess.